# Rust, Attach the lifetime of a closure in a constructor to the object instead of the cosntructor?

Tags: rust, reference, lifetime, borrow-checker

Imagine you want to make an object that constructs s closure and becomes its owner, so that it can issue handles to it, this is MWE I managed to make:

```
struct A<'a>
{
    data: &'a usize,
    function: Box<dyn Fn(&usize) -> usize>,
    b: B<'a>
}

struct B<'a>
{
    f: &'a  dyn Fn(&usize) -> usize
}

impl<'a> A<'a>
{
    pub fn new(data: &'a usize) -> A<'a>
    {
        let closure = Box::new(|i : &usize| {*i});
        
        Self
        {
            data,
            function: closure,
            b: B{f: closure.as_ref()}
        }
    }
}
```

Rust doesn't like this:

`error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable` closure``

But in principle this should be fine. `B` is a field of `A` and will live for the exact same amount as `A` in all instantiations. So `B` can borrow data from `A` with no risk.

The reason this is a problem is that rust has no true concept of a constructor. As far as it is concerned, `closure` exists only in the scope of the `new`, even though the whole point is to shove it into `A`. The BC thus is incapable of proving correctness, even though this is a very sane use of references in this specific context.

For example this will compile:

```
struct A<'a>
{
    data: &'a usize,
    function: Box<dyn Fn(&usize) -> usize>,
    b: B<'a>
}

struct B<'a>
{
    f: &'a  dyn Fn(&usize) -> usize
}

impl<'a> A<'a>
{
    pub fn new(data: &'a usize) 
    {
        let closure = Box::new(|i : &usize| {*i});
        
        let b = B{f: closure.as_ref()};
    }
}
```

which is essentially the same idea. What can I do here?